# Can multiple trainers catch the same Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

Pokemon Scarlet and Violet introduce a more streamlined multiplayer mode, where trainers can explore around the map together. When playing with other trainers, can more than one trainer catch the same Pokemon? Or can only one trainer catch that Pokemon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [this article](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/can-your-friends-see-the-same-shiny-pokemon-in-co-op-in-pokemon-scarlet-and-violet/) about shiny Pokemon, but it works for your question, too:

> The bad news is the shiny Pokemon that you and your friends will encounter will be the same across each screen. So, if you all find it simultaneously, **only one of you can meet and catch the Pokemon**. There’s no way to share the Pokemon or have multiple spawns, so everyone comes away with a shiny Pokemon.

It seems that only one trainer can battle and catch that specific wild Pokemon.

Comment: So my "friends" can turn into Team Rocket? :(

Comment: What if you enter battle with it at the same time as the other person?

Comment: @Riley I feel there's no "same time", it's really hard to get the same exact frame. And in any case the game will decide which player can battle.