# How does the shiny charm affect union circles?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

I'm making much slower progression than my trainer friends, who have already finished the game and completed the Pokedex. As a result, they all have their shiny charms. Since all the spawns appear for everybody (and [only one person can catch a spawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/400285/124566)), how does the shiny charm work in a union circle?

If I join in a friend's union circle, will I be able to take advantage of their shiny charm (since they are hosting the session), or does the shiny charm simply not take affect while in a union circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Union Circles bind the world of the host together with the users that join that world. All the Pokémon on that world are bound to the users in the proximity of that Pokémon.

So if all 4 of you would be standing together, then all Pokémon around you have the same ID and statistics. So if one person has a Shiny Charm the chances are the same for everyone. Killing a Pokémon around you will spawn a Pokémon with the same chance as everyone in the proximity to spawn a shiny.

If you were standing alone in that world with no-one in the proximity the Pokémon spawning around you will have your shiny spawn chance.

If multiple people have the charm, I would suggest splitting up to increase the chance of a shiny. However only 1 person will be able to catch it (unless the host soft reset saves the world).

TLDR;
Yes, it does give you an advantage as long as you are within the proximity of the user.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your answer!